# Liferay and ZK Integration : User Info

Tags: liferay, portlet, portal, zk

I wrote a portlet and added to liferay.

I have found the way to get user name from cookie: 
https://www.everit.biz/web/guest/blog/-/blogs/getting-current-liferay-user-in-a-standalone-webapp?_33_redirect=/web/guest/blog

I have looked into the zk liferay package, there is just JQuery related classes.
http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/6.0.0/zk/org/zkoss/zkplus/liferay/package-summary.html

Is there any way to get the current user in ZK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow simple pattern

In the main Entry controller class, the class which extends the **DHtmlLayoutPortlet**

In the process method you can setup **commonParameter** of liferay to **zk-session**

I am providing you code snippet :

```
 @Override  
      protected boolean process(Session sess, RenderRequest request,  
                RenderResponse response, String path, boolean bRichlet)  
                throws PortletException, IOException {  
           setupSessionParameters(sess, request);  
           return super.process(sess, request, response, path, bRichlet);  
      }  
      protected void setupSessionParameters(Session sess, RenderRequest request) {  
           ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);  
           PortletSession portletSession = request.getPortletSession();  
           PortletPreferences prefs = request.getPreferences();  
           sess.setAttribute("SESSION_ID", portletSession.getId());  
           sess.setAttribute("THEME_DISPLAY", themeDisplay);  
           sess.setAttribute("GROUP_ID", themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId());  
           sess.setAttribute("PORTLET_PREFERENCES", prefs);  
           sess.setAttribute("PORTLET_ID", themeDisplay.getPortletDisplay().getId());  
           sess.setAttribute("currentUser", themeDisplay.getUser().getScreenName());  
      }
```

Use that **zk session** for getting those parameters in your application

If you want more information

[Follow this link](http://integrating-java.blogspot.in/2013/05/explore-power-of-zk-liferay-integration.html)

It has all information that you want ...:)

Answer (score 0):

```java
Execution exe = Executions.getCurrent();
Session session = Sessions.getCurrent();
PortletSession ps = (PortletSession) session.getNativeSession();
User user = PortalUtil.getUser((HttpServletRequest) exe.getNativeRequest());
user.getUserId();
```